# Julia: List docstrings inside a module

Tags: module, julia, docstring

Is there a way to pull ALL the docstrings from the following module `main`, including the docstrings of module `nested`, which reside inside module `main`, **without already knowing what modules are inside module `main`**?

```
"This is Module main"
module main

"This is fA()"
fA(x) = x

"This is module nested"
module nested

"This is fB()"
fB(x) = x

end

end
```

I can get the docstrings for module `main` and module `nested`, assuming I already know that module `nested` exists inside module `main`.

```
? main
This is Module main
? main.nested
This is Module nested
```

I am familiar with `names()`, which helps, but not that much in its simplest incantation:

```
names(main, all = true)
7-element Array{Symbol,1}:
 Symbol("##meta#252")
 Symbol("#eval")     
 Symbol("#fA")       
 :eval               
 :fA                 
 :main               
 :nested
```

Interpreting the output of `names()`is not easy: it's not obvious that `nested` is a module inside `main`.

Comment: ``isdefined(main, :fB)`` returns ``false``, which is not terribly intuitive, except if ``isdefined`` is intended to check only around nested modules, but not inside of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not entirely clear, but here is some useful code:

```
# check if a symbol is a nested module
issubmodule(m::Module, s::Symbol) = isa(eval(m,s),Module) && module_name(m) != s

# get a list of all submodules of module m
submodules(m) = filter(x->issubmodule(m,x),names(m,true))

# get a list of all docstring bindings in a module
allbindings(m) = [ [y[2].data[:binding] for y in x[2].docs]
  for x in eval(m,Base.Docs.META)]

# recursively get all docstrings from a module and submodules
function alldocs(m)
    thedocs = map(x->Base.Docs.doc(x[1]),allbindings(m))
    return vcat(thedocs,map(x->alldocs(eval(m,x)),submodules(m))...)
end
```

Now you have:

```
julia> alldocs(main)
  This is fA()
  This is Module main
  This is module nested
  This is fB()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: excellent answer considering the question was not entirely clear, thanks!

Comment: Does any of this still work? `? main.nested` now returns `ERROR: UndefVarError: NestedModule not defined`